# Using $.get, need to initialize variables on a hidden page

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have the following lines of code to bring up a page that has multiple pages it loads that can be brought up by clicking on the tabs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});

</script>

...

<div id="tabBarArea">
    <div id="tabBarContainer">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li id="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li> -->
            <li id="readingListTab"><a href="#books">Commander's Reading List</a></li>
            <li id="moviesTab"><a href="#movies">Lecture Series</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="tab_container">
        <div id="home" class="tab_content">
            <div id="homeHeaderGraphic" class="header">
                <img id="homeHeaderGraphicImage" src="images/CommandProfessionalDeveloment%20ResourceGuide%20Header-Title.png">
            </div>
            <div id="homeContent" class="contentArea">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $.get("Home.html", function(data){
                        $("#homeContent").empty().append(data);
                     }, "html");
                    resizeContentAreaHeight("home", "homeHeaderGraphic", "homeContent");
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="books" class="tab_content">
            <div id="booksHeaderGraphic" class="header">
                <img id="booksHeaderGraphicImage" src="images/Commander%27sReadingList%20Header.png">
            </div>
            <div id="booksContent" class="contentArea">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $.get("CommanderReadingList.html", function(data){
                        $("#booksContent").empty().append(data);
                     }, "html");
                    resizeContentAreaHeight("books", "booksHeaderGraphic", "booksContent");
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="movies" class="tab_content">
            <div id="moviesHeaderGraphic" class="header">
                <img id="moviesHeaderGraphicImage" src="images/LectureSeries%20Logo.png">
            </div>
            <div id="moviesContent" class="contentArea">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $.get("ForumsArchives.htm", function(data, status, xhr){
                        $("#moviesContent").empty().append(data);
                     }, "html");
                    resizeContentAreaHeight("movies", "moviesHeaderGraphic", "moviesContent");
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that when it comes to bringing up the Reading List, it needs some variables on the page initialized, even though it is hidden.  The variables should look something like this with their values:

```
trueLittleBooksResponsiveOffsetTop: 363 
$('#readingListIntro').offset().top: 263 
$('#readingListIntro').css('margin-top'): 0 
$('#readingListIntro').height(): 100 
littleBooksResponsiveTop: 365 
littleBooksResponsiveHeight: 0 
bookMenuBarHeightToMove: 161 
readingListIntroTop: 263 
readingListIntroHeight: 100
```

but it comes up like this when the Home tab is the first thing to come up.

```
trueLittleBooksResponsiveOffsetTop: 0
$('#readingListIntro').offset().top: 0
$('#readingListIntro').css('margin-top'): 0px
$('#readingListIntro').height(): 0
littleBooksResponsiveTop: 0
littleBooksResponsiveHeight: 0
bookMenuBarHeightToMove: -204
readingListIntroTop: 0
readingListIntroHeight: 0
```

As I can tell, the problem is that the second tab is not visible during the page start up.  When I make the books tab the first one visible, it initializes correctly, yet when I use the home page as the first tab, it gives me the bad variables.  I need to get the variables for the page not visible to initialize.

Comment: What was the thinking on putting those `script` tags into the `div`s instead of putting them all inside `$(document).ready()`? The `$.get()` is making an asynchronous server call, so a lot of factors determine how fast those pages load into the background.

Comment: what do you mean by "the Reading List" ? Your entire question is sort of confusing. Try modifying it so that we can understand it better or else you might end up with unwanted answers.

Answer (score 1):

You may use, just for calculation, either of the set of the following CSS to make the page visible and calculate the stuff and revert it back:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: -200%;
```

Or something else:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
visibility: hidden;
```

The above CSS has to be set inside the `success` function of the AJAX event.

Answer (score 0):

I took away a bit of the dynamics of the page that is loaded into the div, and hard coded the height of the graphic book menu bar, so that the graphic book menu bar stays the same the whole time.  Then the initial calculation doesn't have to be done.  I guess, as long as the variables can't change (too much)  the need for calculations goes away.  Not the nicest, but I'm in a limited environment, so the users shouldn't need too much difference.